# Excel Date Formula to find date for the 2nd business day of the next month

Tags: excel, date

I have a spreadsheet with the the month I'm reporting on, but I want work out the due date, which is the 2nd business day of the following month.

```
Report Month               Due Date
January-13                 04-Feb-13
```

Thank you,

Comment: Before anyone votes to close this please remember that this is a programming question as Excel formulae are programming the Excel API and we all know that you can also use VB program it.

Comment: `=WORKDAY(EOMONTH(B2,0)+1,2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2007 or later or if you are using have Excel 2003 or earlier and have the Analysis toolpack add-in enabled, you can use [`EOMONTH`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/eomonth-HP005209076.aspx) to find the first day of the month (`EOMONTH` returns the last day of the month, so add 1 day to it for the first day of the next month) and [`WORKDAY`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/workday-HP005209339.aspx) to find the second work day after the date returned by `EOMONTH`.

If you do not want to factor holidays into this, the formula would look like:

`=WORKDAY((EOMONTH("January-2013",0)),2)`

If you did want to factor holidays into this, you need to add a third agrument to the `WORKDAY` function call with a list of dates of the holidays you want included. The easiest way to handle build the list is to use a range containing the dates of the holidays.

TechRepublic has a [good post](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/use-excels-workday-function-to-determine-delivery-dates/623) on the `WORKDAY` function.

One thing I would caution you about is, if possible feed the month in using the format `Month-YYYY` instead of `Month-YY` as excel will usually interpret a date entered as `Month-YY` as being `Month-DD-Current year`. Microsoft goes as far to recommend using the `date` formula to build the dates being passed into these functions instead of using text values for them.

Comment: The formula @TimWilliams posted in his comment will be one day later than the 2nd business day of the month but it made me realize I could simplify my example code.

Comment: +1 Note that Analysis ToolPak os  usine Excel 2003 or earlier. In Excel 2007 or later both EOMONTH and WORKDAY are built-in functions

Comment: Sorry, my comment became garbled - should say `"Analysis ToolPak is only required if you are using Excel 2003 or earlier......"`

Comment: Thanks @barry I have always used Excel with the Analysis Toolpack installed and enabled so I didn't even realize that `EOMONTH` and `WORKDAY` have become part of the base product. I updated my answer to include reflect this.